# Crashlytics connection refused - failed to connect to failed to connect to api.crashlytics.com

Tags: android, crashlytics

I'm receiving the following error when starting my app.  Configured Crashlytics with the plugin - appropriate entries in build.gradle, AndroidManifest.xml, crashlytics.properties exists.  Starting Crashlytics from my Application class.  I get this every time.  I'm not behind a proxy or anything.

```
E/Crashlytics﹕ Error performing auto configuration.
com.crashlytics.android.internal.aD: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to api.crashlytics.com/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.a(SourceFile:2582)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.b(SourceFile:2562)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.b(SourceFile:2548)
        at com.crashlytics.android.a.a(SourceFile:81)
        at com.crashlytics.android.a.a(SourceFile:50)
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.a(SourceFile:895)
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.a(SourceFile:54)
        at com.crashlytics.android.t.a(SourceFile:839)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aa.run(SourceFile:13)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to api.crashlytics.com/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.i(SourceFile:2486)
        at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.j(SourceFile:2499)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hemal from Crashlytics here. Can you check if any ad-blocking software is interfering with the connection?

Comment: Hi @hemal I used fabric crashlytics and got the same error with the question. I'm sure that I had no any ad-blocking softwarein my phone. but any idea to solve this??

Comment: is that supposed to be the accepted answer? Why if I don't have any ad-blocking software?

Comment: Answers like this should be a comment. Where do we start checking for this?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem on Xiaomi M4. As was mentioned above if you don't have any ad-blocking application then the main reason is `/ets/hosts` file.

You can check this guess from command line:

```
adb shell # run a shell there
cat /etc/hosts | grep crashlytics # print file content and filter it by 'crashlytics' word
```

and if you see something like this list of lines then it's that problem which you are looking for:

```
127.0.0.1 api.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 apps.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 beta.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 blog.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 calendar.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 docs.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 download.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 e.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 report.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 reports.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 settings.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 support.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 try.crashlytics.com
127.0.0.1 www.crashlytics.com
```

To fix this problem you should comment them. The idea how to do that I found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110483), but I couldn't edit file by vi. So I just pulled, changed and pushed back the `hosts` file. Be attentive: your device must be rooted to do this.

```
adb pull /etc/hosts ./<your_computer_directory> # get hosts file from device
```

just comment lines like this:

```
#127.0.0.1 api.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 apps.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 beta.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 blog.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 calendar.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 docs.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 download.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 e.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 report.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 reports.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 settings.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 support.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 try.crashlytics.com
#127.0.0.1 www.crashlytics.com
```

You can't push it back without root rules. So push it into some tmp user directory:

```
adb push ./<your_computer_directory>/hosts /mnt/sdcard/hosts
```

Then enter as root and replace `/etc/hosts` file:

```
adb shell # run a shell there
su # become the root (don't miss confirmation request!)
mount -o remount,rw /system # allow to write
cp /mnt/sdcard/hosts /etc/hosts
rm /mnt/sdcard/hosts
mount -o remount,ro /system # get things back to normal
exit # unroot
nslookup YourBlockedAdSite.Net # check if it works
exit # good bye
```

Profit!

Answer (score 5):

Faced same problem, AdAway blocked crashlytics.com. Just added this host to white list.

Answer (score 3):

If you have AdAway installed as an ad blocker. You can whitelist Crashlytics APIs by following these steps:

- From the AdAway Menu, select "Your Lists".
- Select the (second) tab labelled "WHITE".
- Tap the plus button on the action bar, a hostname prompt should appear.
- Enter `*.crashlytics.com`, then tap add.
- It should appear as a list item under the "WHITE" tab, ensure it is checked.
- Go back to the main menu, then download and apply ad blocking again.

Your device should be able to access Crashlytics APIs now.

P.S.: Even if you have no ad blocking software installed, some mobile phone manufacturers have a default blacklist enabled on their device as some sort of ad blocking feature. Usually, there's a settings option to disable it. But your mileage may vary. You can check your android device's host file (`/etc/hosts`) to make sure it's not from your manufacturer (if you're not rooted). 
Also, VPN software may block hosts via DNS, so be sure to check that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether your device is installed with any kind of ad blocking software, or your hosts file is modified to block ads.
If your device is rooted then you can check hosts file under /etc/hosts for "127.0.0.1 crashlytics.com" line. Probably this line is causing that issue.

Add crashlytics.com to white list of AdAway and test your app.

Cheers